# Why perl put empty on my database while it has value?

Tags: perl, postgresql

I'm working on a project and I want to insert some data into a database.  I created the database and tables, but I am having some problems.

I decided to write a test program, here is my program code:

```
#!/us/bin/perl                                                                                                                                
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

my $localtime = localtime(time);
print $localtime,"\n",;
my $char_data;
open(my $fh, "<", "/root/testfile/1453800452_5.117.219.107.bin");

while (<$fh>){
    $char_data .= $_;
}
print $char_data,"\n",;
my @Record = unpack('C*',$char_data);
my @IMEI = splice @Record,0,17;

my $IMEI = pack('C*',@IMEI);
  #print$IMEI,"\n";                                                                                                                             
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=test;host=localhost","postgres", "", {PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1});
my $sth=$dbh->prepare(qq/insert into testtime(time,data,imei) values(?,?,?)/);
$sth->execute($localtime,$char_data,$IMEI);
```

and here is my db:

```
time -----> timestamp without time zone

data------->text

imei-------->varchar
```

and here is content of my opened file:

^@^O356307043839678^@^@^@^@^@^@^AM^H^K^@^@^AR}DB^H^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\356^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}CW0^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\357^@^@^\
H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}Bl\224^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\356^@^@    ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}A\201\344^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\357^@^@        ^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}@\227>^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\351^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}?\254\254^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\347^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^AR}>\302^P^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}=\327j^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}<\354\330^@^\
^\2458\340^UJ(\300^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR}<^B2^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\213^@(^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^AR};^W\226^@^^\2458\340^UJ(\300^D\
\215^@(^L^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@~A

My problem is each time that I run the program, only localtime is inserted into database, both imei and data will remain empty.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you verify that $char_data and $IMEI are set properly on the Perl side?

Comment: @Thilo yes i print them with dumper.they got value properly in every run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't allow columns with a data type of `text` to contain null characters, and the strings you are trying to store in both your `data` and `imei` columns start with a null character

You should use a data type of `bytea` instead

Also, you should use an IO mode of `:raw` when you are reading binary files, and rather than concatenating multiple lines you should set the record separator `$/` to `undef` like this

```
my $char_data = do {
    open my $fh, '<:raw', '/root/testfile/1453800452_5.117.219.107.bin' or die $!;
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};
```

And rather than use `unpack` to aplit your string into an array and then `pack` to reform it into a string, it is much more convenient to use `substr` to select part of the string like this

```
my $IMEI = substr $char_data, 0, 17
```

---

You need to do a little more than just pass the strings to the `execute` method when you are using non-standard data types. Here's an example program that shows you how to associate data types with the placeholders in a newly-prepared statement. It needs to be done only once for each statement handle. Thereafter, DBI will know how to translate each parameter passed to `execute`

I have called `bind_param` only for the second and third placeholders. PostgreSQL is happy with a simple string value for `time` datatypes

I have used `Data::Dumper` to display the contents of the `$imei` variable before it is written to the database, as well as all the values in the record after it is retrieved from the database. As you can see, the two match as they should

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use DBI;
use DBD::Pg qw/ PG_BYTEA /;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

my $char_data = do {
    open my $fh, '<:raw', '1453800452_5.117.219.107.bin';
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my $imei = substr $char_data, 0, 17;
say Dumper $imei;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:Pg:dbname=test;host=localhost",
    'postgres', '',
    {
        PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1,
    }
);

$dbh->do('DROP TABLE test');

$dbh->do(<<'END_SQL');
CREATE TABLE test (
    "time"  timestamp without time zone,
    "data"  bytea,
    "imei"  bytea
)
END_SQL

my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO test (time, data, imei) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$insert->bind_param(2, undef, { pg_type => PG_BYTEA });
$insert->bind_param(3, undef, { pg_type => PG_BYTEA });

$insert->execute(scalar localtime, $char_data, $imei);

my @row = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT * FROM test');

say Dumper \@row;
```

#### output

```
"\0\017356307043839678"

[
  "2016-01-31 17:20:08",
  "\0\017356307043839678\0\0\0\0\0\0\1M\b\13\0\0\1R}DB\b\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\356\0\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}CW0\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\357\0\0\34 H\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}Bl\\224\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\356\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}A\\201\\344\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\357\0\0 \0\0\\ \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}\@\\227>\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\351\0\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}?\\254\\254\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\347\0\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\34 \@\0\1R}>\\302\20\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}=\\327j\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}<\\354\\330\0\34 \0342458\\340\25J(\\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R}<\0022\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\213\0(\13\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1R};\27\\226\0\36\\2458\\340\25J(\\300\4\\ \\215\0(\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\13\0\0~A\n",
  "\0\017356307043839678"
]
```

Comment: thanks for youre answer.firs time  i created my table i used bytea but i didnt get result because i didnt know about the rule you mentioned about postgres.now after i did what ever you said,my table filled with \x on data and imei columns.where is problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *“my table filled with \x”*? Please can you read the data using a SELECT statement with Perl DBI and dump the results using `Data::Dumper` with `$Data::Dumper::useqq` set to 1?

Comment: when i select on postgresql i got table as result like this:
imei---->\x
data---->\x
time---->2016-01-31 14:12:17 
and when i print the result of select command execute in my program the result was $var1=''

Comment: @farzane.dezhband: If you need to use non-standard data types, you can't just alter the columns in the database -- you must also use `bind_param` in your Perl code to mark each placeholder according to the type in the database. I have added to my solution to show you how to use non-standard data types in your program

Comment: thank you very much Borodin.this solve's my problem and i learn new things too ;) :)